# Logistic regression for self-regulation

Tags: regression, logistic

My dataset contains samples of the following variables:

- $X_0$: the state of the system at time 0 (a continuous scalar)
- $X_1$: the state of the system at time 1 (a continuous scalar)
- $Y$:  some binary variable describing the system at time 1
- $\boldsymbol{C}$: a bunch of covariates

I would like to investigate whether the system "auto-regulates" by investigating whether larger $X_0$ tends to lead to larger $Y$ which, in turn, leads to smaller $X_1$. If this is the case, then, through the variable $Y$, the state of the system tends to be regulated. The way I have been looking at it for now is through a logistic regression:
$$
\text{logit } Y = \beta_0 + \beta_{x,0}X_0+\beta_{x,1}X_1+\boldsymbol{\beta_c}\boldsymbol{C}
$$
I realized that whenever $\beta_{x,0}$ is positive and significantly different from zero, $\beta_{x,1}$ is negative and significantly different from zero (Wald test). Regardless of the details of the estimation (accounting for multi-collinearity, etc.), I am wondering whether the logistic regression is the right way to approach such a problem and, if not, what other types of model could I investigate.

Comment: Do you have multiple data points on the same system at different points in time? If so, you need to take that into account. This would be a time-series, not a cross-sectional dataset.

Comment: Hi gung,
I do not have multiple data points of the same system, only multiple similar systems with the above-mentioned variables.